# Rendering partial form

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, partial-views, active-form

Is there any way to render partial view which contains a part of form that it's main part is in another view file with AJAX?

I exactly mean one form variable:

```
`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,]); ?>`
```

For Example :

**Controller**

```
public function actionOlddetform()
    {
        return $this->renderAjax('_olddet');
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->input() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'annotations')->textarea(['rows' => 3]) ?>

<div id="details-form"></div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Part of form included with AJAX for `details-form` container depends on `date` value. I know how to check date and show any content of that partial view but when I want to include a part of form I get an error:

```
PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: form'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to actually pass the `model` into your view:

```
public function actionOlddetform()
{
    return $this->renderAjax('_olddet', ['model' => $dataModel]);
}
```

And if you want to render "sub-views" from your main view, you need to pass the variables in there as well (even though I don't see a render call in your view):

```
<?= $this->render('_formPart', ['form' => $form, 'model' => $model]) ?>
```

Comment: I'm passing model variable in actionCreate... What is `$dataModel` variable?

Comment: `$dataModel` is whatever contains your actual data, the `ActiveRecord`-derived model. You are using it in your view as `$model` but you aren't passing it in.

Comment: Now I'm getting `PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: dataModel' ` Are you sure this variable is AD-derived model?

Comment: Of course, rendering partial views in main view, even forms is clear to me, but I want to load sub-view of form depending on value.

Comment: There's no render call in my way because the way I want to do it is AJAX: `$.ajax({
                              url: "/order/olddetform",
                              dataType: "html",
                              success: function(data) {
                                 $("#details-form").html(data);
                              }
                        });`

Comment: @user1900685: You need 2 different variables to do the active form thing: The "`$model`", which you pass to the view when your call `renderAjax()`. This is what contains your data and what you will save in the database. I don't know what underlying model you use so I just used a generic name. Might be `$model = new Olddet();` or whatever, we don't have that information. 
And the $form which is created in the view already. I see no reference of your data model anywhere.

Comment: I see, but don't know how to pass this existing variables with AJAX to my controller to action that renders this partial view. Is passing them in session the only way to do it? Is there any other way like in asp.net mvc (tempdata, viewbag)?

Comment: I can't think of anything, it's just not something that I ever saw being done. What are you trying to do exactly, a multi page form or something?

Comment: Some wizard. Next steps forms depends on previous values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78286/discussion-between-user1900685-and-blizz).